# Getting Started with VB.net for Excel

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2010, vba

I have written an add in for Excel in VBA, but I would now like to convert it to VB.Net.  I have been looking at VB.net tutorials and I read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192490%28v=office.11%29.aspx) but I am still confused on getting started.

I have started a new Excel Add-In Project and have this code:

```
Public Sub Test1()
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object

    'Start a new workbook in Excel.
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

    oSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "HEY!"

End Sub
```

This starts up Excel in a new window and I get the standard Excel new worksheet or template prompt, and when I choose blank workbook the "HEY!" does not appear.

Also, I want this to be an add in that works with the current active sheet, not starting a new one.  Am I going about this wrong?

Edit:  I don't see how this question is too broad tbh.  I have provided code that I have basically copied from a tutorial and said exactly what the code is doing, and what it should be doing.  Its certainly a beginner question, but not too broad imo.  Please let me know what I can do to fix it.

Comment: Look up `VSTO` (*Visual Studio Tools for Office*)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
oSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "HEY!"
```

Try:

```
oSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "HEY!"
```

For more info, see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301982).

Comment: I tried this and I got the same result.  I see that I need to add the property in there though.  But I even tried copying the first 12 lines from the first sub in the link you provided and I still got the same result.  Also, is this what I need to be doing if I want to create an add-in instead of an app that opens Excel and creates a new workbook?